# Lebesgue measurable functions and the absolute value of them

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ is a measurable function. If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, is the absolute value of $f$ Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: What is the definition of a Lebesgue integrable function that you have?

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.